# Duplicate questions in the bounties list on the user profile

Tags: support, bounties, profile-page

I just saw this on the [Jeff's profile page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=bounties#bpage_1-bsort_undefined). I'm not good in all bounties system, so not tagging this as a "bug", but it looks like a bug, Can somebody explain is this normal situation or is it bug?

[image]

Comment: Note: I think [adding the offered-date](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99915/could-the-date-a-bounty-was-offered-be-added-to-the-profile-page) would help clarify this confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see this in that question to confirm, but I have a question [listed twice under my bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1114/jeremy-banks?tab=bounties) because I posted two bounties for it. That is probably what happened here as well.

Answer (score 2):

He offered more than one bounty on the question.