# Could the date a bounty was offered be added to the profile page?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties, dates

In order to prevent [this sort of confusion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99909) could the date that a bounty was offered be added as an extra column in the profile page?

[image: Picture of my user profile bounties offered]

Perhaps just "*offered*: Jul 14th"?

**Update:** Because on Jeff's profile, for example, we see:

[image: Two bounties offered]

Comment: +1 good point. Glad to be an example of confused user)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, done now!

[image: it is done]