# What's the purpose of the tagline in the Bounties section of the profile?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, bounties

This struck me as rather odd. The Bounties section of any given profile, for any of the three tabs (active, offered and earned), contains a list of post links with the amount of rep of the bounty in question. It also has a tagline that indicates, as far as I can tell, the same 'activity' link that's on the front page.

[image]

I find this a weird place for such a link. If A awarded B a bounty, I'm not really that interested in whether C or D edited their answer later on. I'm more interested in when the bounty was awarded and links to B (resp. A) on A (resp. B)'s profile. (To the extent I'm interested in anything on that row, that is.)

This is apparently still the case in the new profile page, so maybe this is something to fix as part of that package. I found [this related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99915/could-the-date-a-bounty-was-offered-be-added-to-the-profile-page) here but I'm still confused about this part.

Is there some specific rationale for this? Or is this just the standard code for question lookup?

Comment: [Cross-posted from meta.physics.se](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6490/whats-the-purpose-of-the-tagline-in-the-bounties-section-of-the-profile).

Comment: That's the standard view for "Question Summary", the team saw no reason to spend time on creating different view for each tab i.e. [tag:status-not-worth-much-efforts]. :)

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Shadow Wizard in the comments, this tagline just seems to be standard part of the question summary used in many parts of the site (other user profile tabs, search results, the front page, etc.), and simply wasn't explicitly disabled for the bounties tab.

That said, I agree that the tagline is confusing here, especially since it just shows a raw timestamp with no explanation of *what happened at that time*, easily leading one to assume that it probably refers to the time when the bounty was placed or awarded (which it doesn't).

IMO, it would be best if the tagline could **actually be changed to show the time when the bounty was awarded** (or, if still active, placed).

Failing that, it should at least have some kind of explanation (like the words "asked" / "edited" / etc., as shown e.g. in search results) added to it, or, alternatively, simply removed.  This last option could be achieved with minimal effort using a CSS rule like the following:

```css
#user-tab-bounties #bounties-table .started { display: none }
```

In fact, I've just added this rule to the development branch of [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch); if no unexpected issues arise in testing, it will be included in the next stable release, v1.30.